# How to check if a relative Path exist in VBA

Tags: vba

I'm trying to check if a directory exists or not.

I tried the following ...

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
 If ReportFolderStatus("\VBAProjectFiles") Then
        MsgBox "Folder exists!"
    Else
        MsgBox "Folder does not exist!"
    End If
End Sub

Function ReportFolderStatus(fldr) As Boolean
   Dim fso
   Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   If (fso.FolderExists(fldr)) Then
      ReportFolderStatus = True
   Else
      ReportFolderStatus = False
   End If
End Function
```

but I get always "Folder does not exist".

The folder structure:

```
--folder#1
 |--folder#2
    |--VBAProjectFiles
    |excel.xlsm
```

Comment: `\VBAProjectFiles` is not the same as `VBAProjectFiles`

Comment: `How to check if the Path “absolute”* exist` - what does that mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want to use

```
ThisWorkbook.Path
```

This will give you the relative path

If that doesn't work, try `ActiveWorkbook.Path` or `App.Path`

```
If Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\VBAProjectFiles", vbDirectory) = "" Then
```

---

Original answer about Absolute path (OP question changed from absolute path to relative path, but I feel this remains useful)

You may be better off putting in the full path

```
if FileExist("c:\VBAProjectFiles\myfile.xml") Then
```

However, despite checking for `FileExist` it appears as if you're actually looking for the existence of a directory. You can use either:

```
If Dir("C:\VBAProjectFiles", vbDirectory) = "" Then
```

or

```
If Len(Dir("C:\VBAProjectFiles", vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
```

or

```
If GetAttr("C:\VBAProjectFiles") And vbDirectory) = vbDirectory then
```

Comment: sorry, my question was absolutly wrong.

Comment: I want to know if a relative path exists

Comment: cool, that's it -> ThisWorkbook.Path

Comment: @PascalC. you only want to use `ThisWorkbook` if the code is in the workbook you're targeting, otherwise use the actual object of the workbook's path.